# Extending native JavaScript objects with Object.create

Tags: javascript

I've been reading [Inheritance and the prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) on the Mozilla Developer Network and have been wondering about something it said.

> One mis-feature that is often used is to extend Object.prototype or one of the other built-in prototypes.

I understand why adding a new function onto a native object's prototype would cause issues.

```
Array.prototype.first = function() { return this[0]; };
```

But suppose someone created a new array and wanted it to have all the functionality of `Array` via its prototype chain, and they did something like this:

```
function MyArray() { Array.apply(this, arguments); }
MyArray.prototype = Object.create(Array.prototype);
MyArray.prototype.first = function() { return this[0]; };
```

Is this method of extending (inheriting from) a native object also considered bad practice?  If so, what problems would it cause?

Comment: http://perfectionkills.com/how-ecmascript-5-still-does-not-allow-to-subclass-an-array/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a general software architecture question, so there can be a lot of different perspectives on what is right or wrong.

My opinion is that native objects should stay native objects. If I were an outsider looking at a code base with a native object being modified, I would be very confused. I could be a javascript guru, but I would be lost and confused at first.

A better way of doing the exact same thing, is instead of extending through inheritance, to extend through composition.

```
function ListClass() {
  var arr = [];
  return {
     first: function() { return arr[0]; },
     get: function(i) { return arr[i]; },
     push: arr.push 
  };
}
```

Your idea is completely valid javascript. The only objection would be code clarity.

Comment: The lack of clarity in `Object.create` applies equally to native and non-native objects.  I don't like it either, but the significant difference is prototype chaining allows `MyArray.length` while composition would require re-implementation or exposing the composed property to get `length`.